# what is the port 33060 for mysql server ports in addition to the port 3306

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2019

background purpose: I want to restrict inbound connection to MYSQL server only for specific host by setting inbound rules of windows firewall.

MYSQL server port is open on 3306.

However, when I open firewall setting, I can see two ports are opened on 3306 and 33060 as follows:

[image]

what is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This connection port is used by the mysql clients to connect to the mysql server. However, in difference to port 3306. These connection uses the so called x-protocol. This port is supported by clients like Mysql-Shell or community Mysql-Connectors, while the mysqlclient and tools like mysqldump are using the classical Port.
The x-protocol is a alternate mysql query interface that includes a alternate API called X-DevAPI. It allows you to access the data in json and also supports SQL.
However, you have to allow it in your firewall settings unless you are deactivating this port/protocol on your mysql-server. So to sum it up for you: The x-protocol and the port 33060 is optional and not necessary.

Reference for general information about mysql Ports:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-port-reference/en/mysql-ports-reference-tables.html

Reference on X-Protocol:
https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/01/07/understanding-mysql-x-all-flavors/

Answer (score 0):

The list of ports used by MySQL are available here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-port-reference/en/mysql-ports-reference-tables.html

For typical usage, you only need port 3306. Check your server configuration files to see what ports it's listening to.